# Adding theme option values as custom body class

Tags: functions, theme-options, body-class

I'm looking to add some custom classes to the body element based on theme options.

I've setup two theme options ('rounded_corner_radio' & 'gradient_radio') that successfully output their values to the front-end using echo so I know they're working.

What I now need to do is insert those values into the body class but can't work out how. Here's what I currently have, any suggestions are very welcome.

```
<?php 
  $rounded_corner_radio = of_get_option( 'rounded_corner_radio' ); 
  $gradient_radio = of_get_option( 'gradient_radio' );
  function custom_body_classes( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = $rounded_corner_radio;
    $classes[] = $gradient_radio;
    return $classes;
  }
  add_filter( 'body_class','custom_body_classes' );
?>
<body <?php  body_class( ''); ?>>
```

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Review how the *variable scope* works.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Let's not add yet another global variable, instead we can e.g. fetch the option values within the filter's callback:

```
function wpse251261_custom_body_classes( $classes ) {

     // Get option values
     $rounded_corner_radio = of_get_option( 'rounded_corner_radio' ); 
     $gradient_radio       = of_get_option( 'gradient_radio' );

     // Assign new body classes
     $classes[] = esc_attr( $rounded_corner_radio );
     $classes[] = esc_attr( $gradient_radio );

     return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class','wpse251261_custom_body_classes' );
```

Note that we escaped it with `esc_attr()`, because the `body_class` filter is applied after such escaping in [`get_body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/).